# Javascript how to merge arrays so that the indexes of original elements in both arrays stays the same

Tags: javascript, array-merge

How can I merge arrays in JS so that the indexes of original elements in both arrays stays the same?

It seems that the spread array does not do what I needed:

```
let testArray: Array<any> = [];
testArray[4] = 'test4';
testArray[2] = 'test2';
testArray[15] = 'test15';

let otherTestArray = [];
otherTestArray[3] = 'test3';
otherTestArray[5] = 'test5';
console.log(testArray);

let testar = [...testArray, ...otherTestArray];
console.log(testar);


2:"test2"
4:"test4"
15:"test15"
19:"test3"
21:"test5"
```

Problem indexes for elements in new array, was changed.

So how can we solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: `let testArray: Array<any> = [];` is not JavaScript. (Not that relevant here, just saying... You might want to edit it out)

Comment: A basic loop will be the best here, so search which array has a value at that index. The best advice would be to avoid these kind of situations, sparse arrays where not every index has a value are a source of errors, because you can't rely on array length anymore. You can't just pass the array to any function without including a check if a value exists, etc. In other words, it just needlessly complicates code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and an array as target.

```js
let testArray = [];
testArray[4] = 'test4';
testArray[2] = 'test2';
testArray[15] = 'test15';

let otherTestArray = [];
otherTestArray[3] = 'test3';
otherTestArray[5] = 'test5';
console.log(testArray);

let testar =  Object.assign([], testArray, otherTestArray);
console.log(testar);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sparse arrays are a pretty bad idea in general, but if you *have* to do this, you can use `Object.assign`:

```js
let testArray = [];
testArray[4] = 'test4';
testArray[2] = 'test2';
testArray[15] = 'test15';

let otherTestArray = [];
otherTestArray[3] = 'test3';
otherTestArray[5] = 'test5';

const finalArr = Object.assign([], testArray, otherTestArray);
console.log(finalArr);

// (16) [empty × 2, "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", empty × 9, "test15"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over each ignoring undefined values and assign the value to another array in the same position...

```js
let testArray = [];
testArray[4] = 'test4';
testArray[2] = 'test2';
testArray[15] = 'test15';
//console.log(testArray);

let otherTestArray = [];
otherTestArray[3] = 'test3';
otherTestArray[5] = 'test5';
//console.log(otherTestArray);

let result = [];
for (var arr of [testArray, otherTestArray]){
  console.log(arr.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== void(0)) // ignore undefined values
      result[i] = arr[i];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```