# How to update an element of an array based on the index when using spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-next

Consider an array as

`const foo = [1, 2, 3];`

Now if I want to replace the second element I can just do:

`foo[1] = 4;` or

`foo.splice(1,1,4);` or

```
const foo = [1, 2, 3];

console.log([...foo.slice(0, 1), 4, ...foo.slice(2)]);
// I know this creates a new array unlike the above two ways.
```

but when we use spread operator for shallow copying objects we can dynamically overwrite a property like:

```
const someObject = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2,
 c: 3
}
const propertyToChange = 'b';

const newObject = { ...someObject, [propertyToChange]: 4 };
```

So, is there an equivalent of this for arrays? Maybe something like the following to change an element based on the index.

```
const newArray = [...oldArray, [dynamicIndex]: 4 ];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort of: you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const newArray = Object.assign([...oldArray], {[dynamicIndex]: 4});
// Or
const newArray = Object.assign([], oldArray, {[dynamicIndex]: 4});
```

That works because arrays are objects.

Live Example:

```js
const oldArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const dynamicIndex = 3; // The fourth entry
const newArray = Object.assign([], oldArray, {[dynamicIndex]: "four"});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Nice. I'm assuming some like `const newArray = [...oldArray, [dynamicIndex]: 4 ];` isn't implemented because of it kind of clashes with the object's syntax. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @RameshReddy - I don't know the specific reason. That does look like it would be awkward for the parser. Up until the `:` it looks like an array literal containing `dynamicIndex`. I *think* they try to avoid too much lookahead when they can...

Comment: (I'm disappointed to see that I didn't include the trick above in Chapter 5 of my book out in June/July [see my profile if you're interested]... :-| Ah, well, there's always the website and perhaps a 2nd edition...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, prior art: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188539/javascript-how-to-merge-arrays-so-that-the-indexes-of-original-elements-in-both

Comment: @NinaScholz - I did wonder if this had been covered somewhere, didn't look hard enough clearly. I've marked the dupe. Can't delete since it's accepted, but...